# Eclipse export Signed APK fails with SDK 12 and Compatibility LIbrary

Tags: java, android, proguard

I'm trying to export a signed obfuscated version of my Android application and I keep getting this error. I recently added the v4 compatibility library and haven't been able to export a signed APK since then. Any help would be appreciated.

Notes: Using SDK 12 and the default proguard.cfg

Here's the console output:

```
Proguard returned with error code 1. See console
Warning: android.support.v4.os.ParcelableCompatCreatorHoneycombMR2: can't find superclass or interface android.os.Parcelable$ClassLoaderCreator
Warning: android.support.v4.os.ParcelableCompatCreatorHoneycombMR2: can't find referenced class android.os.Parcelable$ClassLoaderCreator
Warning: android.support.v4.os.ParcelableCompatCreatorHoneycombMR2: can't find referenced class android.os.Parcelable$ClassLoaderCreator
Warning: there were 3 unresolved references to classes or interfaces.
You may need to specify additional library jars (using '-libraryjars'),
or perhaps the '-dontskipnonpubliclibraryclasses' option.
java.io.IOException: Please correct the above warnings first.
    at proguard.Initializer.execute(Initializer.java:308)
    at proguard.ProGuard.initialize(ProGuard.java:210)
    at proguard.ProGuard.execute(ProGuard.java:85)
    at proguard.ProGuard.main(ProGuard.java:499)
```

Comment: I figured it out.

In addition to:

    -dontwarn **CompatHoneycomb
    -keep class android.support.v4.** {
     *;
    }

I needed to add: 
    -dontwarn **CompatCreatorHoneycombMR2

Answer (score 6, accepted):

-dontwarn **CompatCreatorHoneycombMR2 was the answer.

Comment: This really is no solution. This only doesn't show the message but doesn't resolve the actual problem.